# Is there a way to check the browser's ram usage with selenium (java) /web driver (chrome)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to find/monitor the browser's ram usage while running selenium test cases? (in Java).

It only has to work with the chrome/chrome's selenium driver.

It sounded like there was [potential for this capability (1 1/2 years ago)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/jIF4eMgCutM), but I didn't find much else.